# API style GET without API?

Tags: javascript, api

I have just started working with API and ran into a bit of an issue. Some of the information I need isn't attached to an api, but it is displayed on the site's public website. Is there anyway to grab the raw text from a div on a public website using API style methods? Like:

```
String myString = GET("www.somesite.com/profile#NAMEOFDIV")
```

or something along those lines?

Also, I am using javascript for my application, so I would be okay with a solution that wasn't really an API solution but accomplished the same thing with js.

Comment: You are asking about web scraping. Do a google search with that term and that should give you some guide.

Comment: This looks very promising... thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with Web Scraping. Google search will do.